# oauth not working with jhipster

Tags: jhipster

after generating a jhipster application (folowing the tutorial), the application runs well but I cannot login with my 'user' or 'admin' account. I see the following in the log:

```
[DEBUG] com.chomnoue.jstarter2.security.UserDetailsService - Authenticating jhip
sterapp
```

meaning that the application is trying to authenticate "jhipsterapp" instead of "user".

Following is the content of my .yo-rc.json file

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "baseName": "jstarter",
    "packageName": "com.chomnoue.jstarter",
    "packageFolder": "com/chomnoue/jstarter",
    "authenticationType": "token",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "hazelcast",
    "websocket": "atmosphere",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Memory",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "useCompass": true,
    "frontendBuilder": "grunt",
    "javaVersion": "8"
  }
}
```

any help please?

Comment: As you have some uncommon choices in your yo-rc.json, and that OAuth support is quite recent, you might have hit a bug -> can you submit it on https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues ? And try with all default options excepted OAuth ?

Comment: ok, this is the link https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/341